# How to execute a js function uses elements of another function which brings ajax page

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax, function

In my "index.php" page, I take sth from user and give response in a div using "ajax.php". ajax page returns an ordered list divided into divs called pages. After ajax loaded, I need to execute a function which sets some css properties of the pages. The function is ready and works properly when I attached it to a button's onClick event. But I want execute it automatically after the ajax page loaded. I tried:

1. onload events also in index.php and ajax.php at the top of the page and also at the bottom of the page--> it doesn't work
2. function in function showAjax(){...setCSS();}--> I failed to run it after the whole ajax page loaded
3. callback function--> it doesn't work properly
4. onClick event like that onClick="showAjax(); setCSS();"--> it doesn't work

I don't use jQuery. I examined similar problems solving methods but they don't work. I appreciate anyone saves me from this trouble. Thanks

Code Added:

```
var xmlHttp;

function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else {
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc; 
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true); 
    xmlHttp.send();
}

function showAjax(x) { 
    loadXMLDoc("ajax.php?obj="+x,function() {
       if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("sonuclar").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems to me as though you want to call an XMLHTTPRequest on index.php to ajax.php and return an ordered list with listitems containing divs called pages to index.php that will alter the css presentation of index.php. Show us the ajax implementation you are using in your attempts, and the callback function you have tried.

Comment: I use ajax technic above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. "if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)" this statement is already controlling if the ajax loaded completely. So I add my setCSS function into showAjax function as callback

`function showAjax(x, func) {

```
loadXMLDoc("ajax.php?obj="+x,function() {

   if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200) {

      document.getElementById("sonuclar").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;

      func();

   }

});
```

}

onclick=showAjax(this.value, setCSS);'

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you use your own flavor of ajax, then please take a look at this site I created:
[CV Online](http://www.katarzyna-wojcik.ssl2.pl/k-cv/) , and check my httpreq.js, function OnStateChange. This is called when the ajax request finishes, with success or not. Let me know if this script helps.